# MySQL: call stored procedure within a transaction results syntax error

Tags: mysql, transactions, syntax-error

I called a stored procedure using [DBeaver]https://dbeaver.io.

It generated the following:

```
START TRANSACTION;

{ CALL mydb.myproc() }

COMMIT;
```

However it run into mysql syntax error.

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COMMIT' at line 3
```

If I type the following:

```
START TRANSACTION;
CALL mydb.myproc();
COMMIT;
```

It works as expected.

Why the first one did not work?

Comment: Because of the curly brackets around the stored procedure call?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you use curly braces? Did you read a tutorial or documentation or any example of working code that uses curly braces in MySQL syntax?

Comment: DBeaver is a feature rich database management tool. I suppose it knows why try to use curly brackets here, but nothing is perfect, maybe it is a bug in it.